# How to ensure the correct elements are being added to a recursive datatype?

Tags: sml, smlnj

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Output is truncated with #-signs in the REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532144/output-is-truncated-with-signs-in-the-repl)

Say I have a recursive datatype e.g, accumulating various combinations of fruits

```
datatype fruits = Apple | Orange | Pineapple | Pear
type fruit = fruits;
datatype basket = Empty | Basket of fruit * basket;
```

Now if I add a fruit to a `basket` you would get something like

```
Basket(Apple,Empty)
```

If I were to add a second fruit I get ,

```
Basket(Apple,Basket(#,#))
```

I assume it is this way for display purposes ?

Is there an option/way to check that my basket is filled properly ?

Comment: @sepp2k yeah that was it :), could you change the title of the original ? there was no way I would have found that :/ (You cannot search for `#`)