# Why do I have unexpected '#' in the output for this code?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to create a deriv function to differentiate 
using a datatype as follows:

```
datatype Symex = RCOEFF of real
               | COEFF  of string
               | VAR    of string
               | POWER  of Symex * int
               | NEG    of Symex
               | PLUS   of Symex * Symex
               | MINUS  of Symex * Symex
               | MULT   of Symex * Symex
               | DIVIDE of Symex * Symex
```

here is an example for  a*x^3 + 4.0*x^2 +b*x +c

```
PLUS (MULT (COEFF ("a"),
            POWER (VAR ("x"), 3)),
      PLUS (MULT (RCOEFF (4.0),
                  POWER (VAR ("x"), 2)),
            PLUS (MULT (COEFF ("b"),
                        VAR ("x")),
                  COEFF ("c"))))
```

a part of my code is

```
fun deriv (POWER(a, b)) = MULT(RCOEFF(Real.fromInt(b)), POWER(a, b-1))
```

but when i calculate

```
deriv(POWER(VAR "x", 3))
```

the output is

```
MULT(RCOEFF 3.0 , POWER(VAR # , 3))
```

why is there a '#' in the output?

Please any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5051081/577513

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SML/NJ has a limit on how deep structures are printed to the console. If this limit is reached, a `#` is used to signify, that the structure is larger, but not shown.

If you think the limit is too low, you can change it by updating the value stored in `Control.Print.printDepth` to a value that suits you better.

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.69 [built: Mon Jun  8 14:15:08 2009]

- datatype 'a ls = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a ls;
datatype 'a ls = Cons of 'a * 'a ls | Nil

- Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Nil))));
val it = Cons (1,Cons (2,Cons #)) : int ls

- Control.Print.printDepth;
val it = ref 5 : int ref

- Control.Print.printDepth := 100;
val it = () : unit

- Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Nil))));
val it = Cons (1,Cons (2,Cons (3,Cons (4,Nil)))) : int ls
```