# Increase print depth for lists in SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm using Emacs to write a simple function in sml of about 4 lines and when I try to call the function/evaluate it in the buffer it returns this with 3 dots at the end

```
val it = [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,...] : int list
```

What's the dots at the end? My code doesn't print any dots. Is this is from Emacs or sml? any hints please.

Also I'm supposed to get a longer list like

```
[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

is that why the dots there?

Comment: You are seeing the default print length of whatever version of SML you are using (Emacs is just an editor -- what compiler are you using?). You can change the print length (see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5079394/4996248 , at least for SML/NJ) or you can write your own list-printing function. The REPL is just for development/ debugging. It typically gives you a peak at the values -- not  the full values themselves (which can be quite big).

Comment: V110.75 okay I read the ones above but it's not clear where to put the commands like Control.Print.printDepth:=60; where do I enter this in emacs?

Comment: So you are using SML/NJ. I haven't used Emacs with SML. If there is an interactive mode -- just type it at the prompt. If you are loading files -- just put that towards the top of the file. Experiment. `Control.Print.printDepth:=60;` is just an expression -- evaluate it the same way you evaluated whatever triggered `val it = [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,...]`

Comment: Great thank you! I used Control.Print.printLength := 1024; in the buffer of emacs (where I evaluate my functions) and it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is that why the dots there?

Yes.