# Removing hash from ml output

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I have written an ml function and in the output i am getting
out = Mary ("a",[Zary #,Zary #])
where Mary and Zary are constructors. But as you can see there are some "#" in the output.
if i do 
val Mary("a",x) = out;
then it is showing
x = [Zary("b"),Zary("c")]; which is right.

I want to get the complete output instead of hashes. Kindly help me.

Comment: "ml"? "html"? What is it? Which is it? In any case, it's off topic for this site. Please click the `flag` link and ask a moderator to move it to the correct site. Stack Overflow? Plus, for extra credit, read the FAQ.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [expanding # in sml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051081/expanding-in-sml/5079394#5079394) and [Output is truncated with #-signs in the REPL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532144/output-is-truncated-with-signs-in-the-repl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (as seems to be the case) you're using SML/NJ, then you need to set either `Control.Print.printDepth` or `Compiler.Control.Print.printDepth` (depending on which version of SML/NJ you're using) to a value larger than its default.

The hashes are used as an abbreviation, to make complicated output more manageable. The thresholds governing how complicated a given bit of output has to be before eliding it are rather low. (There's a printLength threshold too, governing elision of long lists as opposed to deeply-nested structures.)

See http://www.smlnj.org/doc/Compiler/pages/printcontrol.html for the official documentation.