# What does '#' mean in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have a function, that creates a new tree, based on an old one, and the min/max values of each node from the old one. using the datatypes:

```
datatype 'a Tree = LEAF of 'a | NODE of ('a Tree) * ('a Tree)
```

and

```
datatype 'a myTree = myLEAF of 'a | myNODE of 'a*'a*('a myTree)*('a myTree)
```

for instance,

```
(NODE(NODE(NODE(LEAF(0),LEAF(9)),LEAF(6)),NODE(LEAF(3),LEAF(10))))
```

should produce:

```
(myNODE(0,10,myNODE(0,9,myNODE(0,9,myLEAF(0),myLEAF(9)),myLEAF(6)),myNODE(3,10,myLEAF(3),myLEAF(10))))
```

Everything seems to work. Except, the values in the leaf and internal nodes are replaced with '#'.

example:

```
 minmaxTree t1;
val it =
  myNODE (1,2,myNODE (1,2,myNODE #,myLEAF #),myNODE (1,2,myNODE #,myNODE #))
  : int myTree
```

Im confused why the sml compiler is replacing with '#', where the values are clearly ints.
Thank you kindly!

Comment: You're correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by molbdnilo, this was a duplicate question, the answer to my question is found here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532144/output-is-truncated-with-signs-in-the-repl)
There was an output restriction, the compiler was not set to print out in depth, as i need it to. after applying the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532144/output-is-truncated-with-signs-in-the-repl),

my output is:

```
- minmaxTree t1;
val it =
  myNODE
    (1,2,myNODE (1,2,myNODE (1,2,myLEAF 1,myLEAF 2),myLEAF 1),
     myNODE
       (1,2,myNODE (1,2,myLEAF 1,myLEAF 2),
        myNODE (1,2,myNODE (1,2,myLEAF 1,myLEAF 2),myLEAF 1))) : int myTree
```

Comment: If you realize that your question is duplicate, why not delete it rather than answer it?

Comment: I wad unable to find the question my question duplicated, when I searched my problem. Others might have the same issue, they could be directed here, and their question will be answered