# Is SML hiding elements of the list?

Tags: list, sml

I was testing the following piece of code:

```
datatype my_int_list = Empty 
                     | Cons of int * my_int_list

fun append (xs, ys) =
    case xs of
        Empty => ys 
      | Cons(x, xs') => Cons(x, append(xs', ys))
```

If I create list of one element, or of two elements, everything is normal. If I create list of three elements it introduces the `#` symbol.

```
- Cons(1, Empty);
val it = Cons (1,Empty) : my_int_list
- Cons(1, Cons(2, Empty));
val it = Cons (1,Cons (2,Empty)) : my_int_list
- Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Empty)));
val it = Cons (1,Cons (2,Cons #)) : my_int_list
```

And this is what happens when I try to use the `append` function:

```
- val l1 = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Empty)));
val l1 = Cons (1,Cons (2,Cons #)) : my_int_list
- val l2 = Cons(4, Cons(5, Cons(6, Empty)));
val l2 = Cons (4,Cons (5,Cons #)) : my_int_list
- append(l1, l2);
val it = Cons (1,Cons (2,Cons #)) : my_int_list
```

Is this just `SML` way of telling that there are more elements but it's not gonna bother to print them? If so, can I ask it to print everything? If not, did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this just SML way of telling that there are more elements but it's not gonna bother to print them?

Yes!

> If so, can I ask it to print everything?

[Yes!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532144/output-is-truncated-with-signs-in-the-repl)

> If not, did I do something wrong?

No!